# Java timer with static method

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, thread-safety

I have a sample code. The output is as expected. Still I have doubt at any point of time is there any possibility that the value passed to and returned are different. As it is static method and it has only one instance. Can multiple threads get value passed by some other thread?? Is is possible?  Code is below

```
    import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Test{

    public static String t(String str){
        return str;
    }
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Timer timer= new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                    System.out.println("Sending - "+"Timer1A"+i+" ---- > got - "+Test.t("Timer1A"+i+""));
                    System.out.println("Sending - "+"Timer1B"+i+" ---- > got - "+Test.t("Timer1B"+i+""));
                    System.out.println("Sending - "+"Timer1C"+i+" ---- > got - "+Test.t("Timer1C"+i+""));
                }
            }
        },1000,10);
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                    System.out.println("Sending - "+"Timer2D"+i+" ---- > got - "+Test.t("Timer2D"+i+""));
                    System.out.println("Sending - "+"Timer2E"+i+" ---- > got - "+Test.t("Timer2E"+i+""));
                    System.out.println("Sending - "+"Timer2F"+i+" ---- > got - "+Test.t("Timer2F"+i+""));
                }
            }
        },1000,10);
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                    System.out.println("Sending - "+"Timer3G"+i+" ---- > got - "+Test.t("Timer3G"+i+""));
                    System.out.println("Sending - "+"Timer3H"+i+" ---- > got - "+Test.t("Timer3H"+i+""));
                    System.out.println("Sending - "+"Timer3I"+i+" ---- > got - "+Test.t("Timer3I"+i+""));
                }
            }
        },1000,10);
    }
}
```

### Regards

Aadam

Answer (score 1):

In your case, method `Test.t` is thread safe. It has no side effect, it does not modify external state.
You could do whatever you want with argument that is passed to the method and return any value - method will be thread safe. Any numbers of threads may call it, and each caller will get own copy of `String str`.

**Edit:** You could do whatever you want with str argument because String is immutable. If you pass mutable object to the method (Collection, for example) then method will be able to change the object. If method will be called from multiple threads, method will not be thread safe- unless argument you mutate is synchronized either externaly (by yourself, in your method) or internally (methods you call are thread safe).